# Stored procedure, return startdate as start of month

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am fairly new to SQL but I am looking at editing a stored procedure that we have so that we don't need to manually enter the @StartDate and @EndDate values. 
The code is below. Basically I would like the StartDate to be the start of the previous month and the EndDate to be the current date. 
This might be quite simple, however I can't find anything online that appears to relate to our issue.

```
USE [OnlineOrdering]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_GetPayPalOrders]
        @StartDate = N'2017-01-01 00:00:00',
        @EndDate = N'2017-01-31 23:59:59'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Just to note, I didn't originally write this procedure, I would just like to be able to automate the dates to make it easier to run.

Thank you

Comment: What is the type of the parameters (date, datetime, varchar) and why are you passing a time component? Are dates stored as `date` or `datetime` with a non-zero time part?

Comment: Your example and your comments do not match, which will only confuse and delay. Perhaps you meant to say that the value of @EndDate should be the last day of the previous month with the time component set as you indicate in your example?

Comment: Hi, yes sorry. @EndDate should be the last date of the previous month. I am going to try a couple of the suggestions listed and see if they fix the issue. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Rigerta's answer was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first day of last month you do this:

> SELECT DATEADD(month,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0))

So, your code would be:

```
USE [OnlineOrdering]
GO

DECLARE @firstDayLastMonth datetime = DATEADD(month,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0)), @now datetime = GETDATE()
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[usp_GetPayPalOrders]
    @StartDate = @firstDayLastMonth,
    @EndDate = @now

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Comment: You don't need to use `SELECT` in the variable declaration

Comment: Yes indeed! The value can just be assigned directly, I will edit the answer. I use it myself for being able to do the select without writing another "select @firstDayLastMonth" statement :)

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last month day for a specific day with [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql), eg:

```
SELECT EOMONTH(GETDATE())
```

Will return `2017-05-31`.

The function accepts a month offset as a second parameter. You can get the last day of the previous month with:

```
SELECT EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)
```

EOMONTH is available in all supported SQL Server versions, ie 2012 and later.

In your case, you could write:

```
declare @start date EOMONTH(GetDate(),-1), @end date = GetDate()

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_GetPayPalOrders] @start, @end
```

This will work if dates are stored as ... dates, ie using the `date` type or `datetime` without a time component. If not, you'll have to add a time offset to @end, eg:

```
declare @start date=getdate(), @endDay datetime=cast(getdate()  as date)
declare @end datetime = @endDay + cast('23:59:59' as datetime)
```